# how to prevent python from printing the binary sign

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to print the comments of  files inside a zip file :

```
import zipfile
def info_zip(archive_name):
   with zipfile.ZipFile(archive_name) as challenge:
       for info in challenge.infolist():
            print(info.comment)
```

but the results i am get aren't pretty:

```
b'G'
b' '
b'E'
b' '
b' '
b'*'
b'*'
b' '
b'E'
```

1. How to get rid from those b at the start of every comment?
2. Why are they like that, i know what they are mean buy isn't the comment's content is by the author of the zip file, why he would like to store them as binary ?

Python 3.x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `b`indicates that it is a [bytes](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=bytes.decode#bytes-and-byte-array-methods)-object that is printed. To get from bytes to string you have to [decode](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=bytes.decode#bytes.decode) the bytes object ([Encode](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=bytes.decode#str.encode) is transform a string to a bytes object).

In order to decode a bytes object you'' have to know the used [character encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding).

My guess is that the zip-file header is simply `ASCII` encoded. You should thus be able to get the wanted result by calling:

```
myBytesObject.decode('ASCII')
```